# How to get messages from an Android device after a specied date in Android programmatically

Tags: android, message

I want to get a device's messages (both sent & received) **after a specified date**. I am using the following logic for getting messages, but I am unable to write logic for the where condition. How do I solve this?

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
String WHERE_CONDITION="";
//Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI,
new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" },
                 WHERE_CONDITION,
                 null, null);

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    address.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
    body.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")));
    id.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    date.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date")));
}
```

Comment: in cursor you will get all data so after that just make query on date field to display data between that date..

Comment: well you can try something like that-
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI,
    new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" },
                     WHERE date BETWEEN '12/1/2012' and '1/2/2013',
                     null, null);

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `java.util.Date` object:

```
Date date = new Date(113,9,1,0,0,0);  // 2013/10/01 00:00:00
long time = date.getTime();
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
String WHERE_CONDITION="date >= ?";

Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI,
new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body" },
                 WHERE_CONDITION,
                 new String[] { Long.toString(time) }, null);

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        address.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
        body.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")));
        id.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        date.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date")));

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps for your query.

```
date.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date")));
```

This code returns date in long format.

1:-Convert this long code to proper date format.

```
long dateInLong=long.parseLong(date.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"))));
String msgDate=DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy",dateInLong).toString;
```

2:-Compare your date and this **msgDate** and show messages that follow requirements

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date d1= sdf.parse(msgDate);
Date d2=sdf.parse("your date in MM/dd/yyyy format");
if(d1.compareTo(d2)>0){
Log.e("","d1 is after d2");
}
else if(d1.compareTo(d2)<0){
Log.e("","d1 is before d2");
}
else
{
 Log.e("","both dates are same");
}
```

That's it.:)